# Get Django South working on Heroku with custom user models?

Tags: django, heroku, django-south, migrate

I'm trying to get South for Django to work on Hereoku. It didn't seem that hard, thanks to [this](http://www.mikeball.us/blog/using-south-on-heroku-hosted-django-project) example. However, I'm using a workaround for a [bug in south](http://south.aeracode.org/ticket/1179) that prevents initiating south when a custom user model is used in Django.

I use the following south commands local to initiate South (work around):

```
python manage.py syncdb
python manage.py convert_to_south myapp
python manage.py migrate myapp 0001 --fake
```

After that I pushed the code to Heroku and tried the following steps on Heroku:

```
python manage.py syncdb // this didn't sync the south apps
python manage.py convert_to_south myapp 
// This gave the error saying that the apps were already added to south
```

My second try (after Heroku db reset and new push):

```
python manage.py syncdb // this didn't sync the south apps
python manage.py migrate 
// Same south error as described in the south bug ticket
```

Is there anyone who can put me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've searched for the answer in many places, but the only solution seems to generate the migrations files locally and push them to Heroku. That's something I wish I could prevent, but it is the only working option.

Hopefully, this will be solves as of Django 1.7, when migrations are built into Django. Until then, I moved away from Heroku.

Comment: Why would you want to avoid generating the migrations locally? They should be in your repo.